# how do I check whether user exists in db or not

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails application, I have relationship setup such has 
user `has_many :contacts`, all the contacts of a user are stored in contacts

when I do `user.contacts` i get all the contacts of a `current_user` I wanted to check how many of the user contacts are already registered meaning already existing in users table. I have some solution in mind my comparing of each contact of a user with the db(users table). But the process will very time consuming looking for a more optimized way.

Comment: Do you need all the users who have contacts in the system right?

Comment: What defines a contact is there a unique key you can use to determine if a contact already exists? (maybe an email address or something to that affect)

Comment: please share output of `describe contacts` and `describe users`.

Comment: I have a simple relationship established user `has_many :contacts` & contact `belongs_to :user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Contact` model has `email` as an attribute and `User` also has `email` as an attribute. To find the number of users that are registered with the emails that are as contacts of `current_user`, you would do:

```
contact_emails = current_user.contacts.pluck("contacts.email")
no_of_users_registered = User.where(email: contact_emails).count
```

Comment: What exactly is it you want? Add some example records. The question is kinda confusing.

Comment: Thanks! for your answer, but I'm not looking for this. What I mean for eg: Let's say user1 has many contacts(email_addresses of his friends) now I want to check how many of his firend's are already registered

Comment: @VibhooMishra I have updated the answer with the solution to that

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. One more thing, this is most optimized way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an association extension to do this:

```
class User 
  has_many :contacts do
    def persisted
      where(email: User.select(:email))
    end
  end
end
```

Assuming both your contact and user models have an email field.